# iPhone / iPad ios 6, 7, 8 UIWebview First Click Looks for Closest input, changes Focus and brings up keyboard

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

We have a UIWebView Page that we are getting from a server that is exhibiting an unusual issue.

The first click on the web view page is doing a "find closest input item, change focus to it" and then the keyboard picker comes up.

This is only happening on the first click on the page.  Would post the HTML, but it is rather large.

Any hints on what to start looking for would be appreciated.

There is no delegate callback with this happens.

Comment: could it be a javascript "joke"?

Comment: Yep, this is what it is looking like right now..... LOL